# Sql query to descending order the datas in table

Tags: mysql

I need to know the sql query to descending order the datas in database table

Comment: Honestly... you couldn't even be bothered to look at a basic sql reference manual to figure this out on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   * 
from     tablename 
order by colname desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `ORDER BY` clause for this. `DESC` is for *descending* while `ASC` for *ascending* and it can be omitted since by default it is sorted in aascending order.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY columnName DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName(adc table)
ORDER BY columnName(example name) DESC
```